# Object(s) appending while using spread operator in setState

Tags: reactjs

I have a state in react like so:

```
{
  questionno: 1,
  questionListData: [
    {
      id:1, 
      question:'which continent India belongs to?', 
      options:[{opt:'Australia'},{opt:'Europe'},{opt:'Asia'},{opt:'Africa'}]
    }
    {
      id:2, 
      question:'New delhi is capital of which country?', 
      options:[{opt:'India'},{opt:'Croatia'},{opt:'Sri Lanka'},{opt:'Latvia'}]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am calling a function on click of a button, which updates any changes i make to the existing options. Inside this onClick function i have made something like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  questionListData: [
    ...prevState.questionListData, 
    ...prevState.questionListData.map((q, z) => {

      // checks the current question number where i made the change in options
      if(z === this.state.questionno-1) {
        q.options.map((g, b) => {

          // this is the changed value is stored somewhere on change
          console.log('dataFromChild[`op_${b}`]: ', dataFromChild[`op_${b}`]);

          g.opt = dataFromChild[`op_${b}`];

        });
      }
      // here IS the problem, i also tried return g, but same result
      return {...{}}
      // this.setState({questionListData: [...this.state.questionListData.slice(0, 3), updatedImage, ...this.state.images.slice(4)]})
    })
  ]
}), () => {
  console.log('hi22:', this.state)
});
```

so the problem is that though i am getting the stored value updated in the state options array, but there is additional `{}` added to the `questionListData`, probably because of the `return {...{}}`. I also tried return g, but then it added the already added values (as expected). SO i just want the changes to get updated on the particular options(which is happening), but the more stuff that is appending on the state is what i don't want. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the modified object in your `map` and remove extra `...prevState.questionListData` because you're basically copying over the same array:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  questionListData: prevState.questionListData.map((q, z) => {
    if (z === this.state.questionno - 1) {
      q.options = q.options.map((g, b) => {

        // this is the changed value is stored somewhere on change
        console.log('dataFromChild[`op_${b}`]: ', dataFromChild[`op_${b}`]);

        g.opt = dataFromChild[`op_${b}`];
        return g; // Return the object here
      });
    }

    return q; // And here
  })
}), () => console.log('hi22:', this.state));
```

Comment: No, even after doing this, the array `questionListData` is getting repeated, i.e, its values are getting duplicated. so if there are 3 questions, they are coming 2 times (Q1 Q2 Q3 Q1 Q2 Q3 ). That is because of the `return q`. If i skip `return q`, there is error. so what do i need to write instead of return q is my question. i tried return null also, but it again gave an error, as it needs to return something.

Comment: @gauravoberoi edited the answer, you need to remove an extra copy of your array.